# A sufficient condition for almost everywhere equality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $f,g:(0,\infty)\to \mathrm{R}$ be monotone decreasing functions.
>
> Show that if
>
> $m(\{x:f(x)>a\})=m(\{x;g(x)>a\}),\; \forall a\in \mathrm{R}$ where $m$ denotes Lebesgue measure,
>
> then $f=g~~~ a.e.$ in $(0,\infty)$.

Here's how I tried to do:

We need to show $m(\{x:f(x)\neq g(x)\})=0$.

Since conditions for $f$ and $g$ are symmetric, it suffices to show $m(\{x:f(x)> g(x)\})=0$.

To derive contradiction, assume $m(\{x:f(x)> g(x)\})>0$.
Then there are $x_1, x_2$ with $x_1<x_2$ such that $[x_1,x_2]\subset \{x:f(x)> g(x)\} $.

By the assumption, we have
$f(x_1)\geq f(x)\geq f(x_2)$, $g(x_1)\geq g(x)\geq g(x_2)~~ {\rm and}~~ f(x)>g(x) ~~\forall x\in (x_1,x_2)$.

If $f$ and $g$ were continuous and strictly decreasing, I can take a small neighborhood of a fixed $x^\star$ and argue that in that nighborhood, which is an open interval, $f(x)>f(x^\star)$ but $g(x)\leq f(x^\star)$, a contradiction.

I can't think of how to prove it without these assumptions.

Any comment or advise is greatly appreciated.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: why you can find a closed interval $[ x_1, x_2]$ ?   b.t.w., you may want to assume (WOLOG) that $f, g$ are in addition, continuous, since the discontinuities of monotone functions have zero LEB- measure

Comment: @Chival: Could you expand why we can assume continuity?

Comment: @Adayah: monotone functions are a.e., continuous.

Comment: @Gary.: Yeah, I've heard that. But how does that allow to assume continuity?

Comment: @Adayah: I think only a.e. continuity is assumed.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$ the sets $\{ x : f(x) > a \}$ and $\{   x : g(x) > a \}$ are of either one of the following forms:

- $\varnothing$
- $(0, \alpha)$
- $(0, \alpha]$
- $(0, \infty)$

for some $\alpha > 0$, thus one is always contained in the other.

Hence if $m \big( \{ x : f(x) > a \} \big) = m \big( \{   x : g(x) > a \} \big)$, then $m \big( \{ x : f(x) > a \geqslant g(x) \} \big) = 0.$ Moreover, for every $x \in (0, \infty)$

$$f(x) > g(x) \implies (\exists q \in \mathbb{Q}) \ f(x) > q \geqslant g(x),$$

so

$$\{ x : f(x) > g(x) \} \subseteq \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \{ x : f(x) > q \geqslant g(x) \}$$

but

$$m \left( \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \{ x : f(x) > q \geqslant g(x) \} \right) = 0.$$

Comment: Thank you. It really helped me.